# Same table name, same schema, different users in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the following requirement:

- TABLE1 is the table name
- Each user should have access to their version of TABLE1
- The data in different TABLE1 tables is managed by their user.
- Users should not have access to other user's TABLE1
- All TABLE1 tables should reside in the same schema
- When a user runs `select * from TABLE1` in a SQL client they should see their version of TABLE1.

Is it possible to achieve this in Oracle?

Comment: Does each user's table actually have to be called the same thing; or could they each have their own uniquely-named table in a common schema and a private synonym with that fixed name? I don't understand why you wouldn't just have each user's table in their own schema though - why do they have to be in a single one? What are you actually trying to achieve and why? Knowing how you got to this list of requirements might suggest other approaches.

Comment: Alex, I need the same name for all the users because I'm offering a service that needs to be uniform, I thought about appending a code to the table name, but first I wanted to make sure that having the same is not possible.

Comment: So why not just let each user have a table in their own schema? Since that's kind of what schemas are for...

Comment: Yes, each user having their own schema is probably what I'll do

Comment: Each user has their own schema anyway; but they need storage quotas and privileges, unless an admin account is creating the users and their tables automatically. (I wondered if you were confusing schemas and tablespaces, but I don't think so.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you wrote is possible, except

- All TABLE1 tables should reside in the same schema

because you can't have two tables with the same name in the same schema.

---

A "schema" = user + its objects (tables, views, procedures, ...). Therefore, each user can have their own `TABLE1` table.

It appears that there's yet another schema which *aggregates* data from everyone's `TABLE1` table. In order to do that, you could create a view as

```
create or replace view v_table1 as
  select 'USER1' owner, t.* from user1.table1 t union all
  select 'USER2'      , t.* from user2.table1 t union all
  ...
```

It means that the final condition you wrote should be expanded a little bit, adding the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
select * from v_table1 where owner = 'USER2'
```

On the other hand, if every user has its own `TABLE1`, why would they query that "aggregated" `(v_)TABLE1`?

Finally, check VPD (virtual private database). In a few words:

> Oracle Virtual Private Database (VPD) enables you to create security policies to control database access at the row and column level. Essentially, Oracle Virtual Private Database adds a dynamic WHERE clause to a SQL statement that is issued against the table, view, or synonym to which an Oracle Virtual Private Database security policy was applied.

More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm#DBSEG98215

Comment: Technically, with VPD it's possible to have a single table1 which each user can see and manipulate only their data. However, that assumes that the table1 for all users has the same structure.

Comment: Yes, @Boneist. That eliminates "every user has to have their own TABLE1 table" as all of them can use the same table. I'm not sure what problem the OP is trying to solve, actually. I just tried to answer the question (whether it is *possible*).

Comment: The table structure should be the same, the name should be the same, but each user should have their own data.

Comment: Worth mentioning that VPD is restricted to Enterprise Edition for regular database and also Oracle Express Edition - since XE 18c(!)